# Opening database .bak file in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000, database-backups

Here is the error I am getting:

> the database was backed up on a server running version 8.00.2050. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 11.00.2218. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.

I understand that this .bak file is not going to be compatible with SQL Sserver 2008 r2, since I looked up what version of SQL Server that particular version is, and it's SQL Server 2000. But is there a third party solution for this? I tried installing SQL Server 2000 and it doesn't install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11.00.2218 is SQL Server 2012, not SQL Server 2008 R2.

In order to restore a SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2012, you need to first restore it on a 2005, 2008 or 2008 R2 server, back it up from there, then restore it to the SQL Server 2012 server.

You can do this by:

1. Installing an Evaluation Edition of any of those versions
2. Finding an existing instance already installed elsewhere
3. Installing Express Edition as long as (a) database size < 10GB and (b) you're not using any features not supported in Express